# Meaning of "to come at the hands of"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

In the sentence "**I expect his end is likely to come at the hands of his own people**", I cannot understand what the author tries to say. I have a serious problem with the below expression:

> ... **to come at the hands of**  ...

Would you please tell me what it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you

> ... to come (to be) at the hands of ...

This is basically the meaning. It means that it will be done by whosever hands you say.

So in your quote:

> I expected his end is likely to come at the hands of his own people

The phrase means that he will be killed by his own people.

Comment: Thanks. What does it naturally is ? I mean if it is an idiom or what ?

Comment: @Cardinal Yes, it is an idiom.